# Java Split("\\|") not working for strings with space

Tags: java, split

for the below input im expecting all the strings delimited with "|" to be available in an array. but only first string is available and the next string is partially available.the rest is not at all available. please help me in understanding it. i explored all the help docs and previous stackoverflow stuff but not able to solve it. i tried with split(String regex,int limit)as well but no use. I dont want to replace the whitespace as i need to retain that.

input "1|New York|1345|134|45634"
Expected output is: 1,New York,1345,134,45634
Actual output is:1,New

```
public class test1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String strinp=scanner.next();
        //System.out.println(strinp.replaceAll(" ", ""));
        String[] strArr=strinp.split("\\|");
        //System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(strArr));
        for (String s:strArr) {
            System.out.println(s);

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Hm, this here produces your expected output:
    String strinp="1|New York|1345|134|45634";
    String[] strArr=strinp.split("\\|");
    for (String s:strArr) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }

Comment: public static void main(String[] args) {
  Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
     String strinp=  scanner.nextLine();
     strinp = strinp.replace('|', ',');
      System.out.println(strinp);
 }

input:"1|New York|1345|134|45634"
output:"1,New York,1345,134,45634"

Answer (score 3):

`scanner.next()` splits on spaces itself. So your first `scanner.next()` call reads `1|New` which you then split.

Use `scanner.nextLine()` to read the whole line, it will be split successfully.

Comment: You beat me to it

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
String strinp = scanner.next();
```

To:

```
String strinp = scanner.nextLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can declare scanner as:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in).useDelimiter("\\n");
```